# UITapGestureRecognizer won't work for custom UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom UIView class which creates a checkbox. This UIView is in a custom table view cell.

I have this code in `cellForRowAt`

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TransactionsTableViewCell
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.addSubview(cell.test)
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.recurringChange(_:)))
    cell.test.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.test.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
  }
```

I have have this function in the ViewController class

```
@objc func recurringChange(_ sender: 
UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("test")
}
```

When `test` view is tapped, it does not print test. I tried this with a normal UIView (not custom), and it worked exactly as expected.

If this helps, here is a link to the custom class: https://github.com/vladislav-k/VKCheckbox

Comment: Where did you write recurringChange(: _) function?

Comment: In the ViewController class

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the code in Xcode 10 and there is no problem.

You may check  " cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true"
and "cell.addSubview(test)" is added to cell before you add TapGesture.

Comment: It works fine with a normal UIView, but it won't work with my custom UIView

Comment: So  please check the cell setting

Comment: I added your two suggestions before I added TapGesture. It still did not work

Comment: post your complete related code. It should work for tablevieWCells with multiple tap gestures.

Comment: could you `print(cell.test)`

Comment: cell.test prints the following: Optional(<Budget4Savings.VKCheckbox: 0x119d800c0; frame = (71 0; 21 21); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280ff3ba0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2801c9700>>)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182615/discussion-between-e-coms-and-jh95).